Multiple Namespace Deployer Properties in Spring Cloud Data Flow
We are in process of having a single SCDF server instance in k8s deploying stream applications to multiple namespaces based on the platformName property.
My question is when i specify a property like this
spring.cloud.skipper.server.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.secretRefs: [ 'mysecret' ]

Assumption is that when a stream is deployed to a diff namespace, these properties will by default applied to apps deployed under new account, unless its explicitly overridden?
Is my understanding of default incorrect or how i can ensure that when an app is deployed using an explicit account that is not "default" gets all those properties from the default account and gets overridden values only when explicitly mentioned as below.
spring.cloud.skipper.server.platform.kubernetes.accounts.new-platform-name.secretRefs: [ 'mysecretnew' ]

so for an stream deployed into new-platform-name, mysecretnew is mounted, but another property like, readinessprobe gets inherited from default?

The name of the default platform is default. It doesn't act as the default values for deployment properties.
You will have to be explicit in providing properties for each platform/account.
These act as default values when you deploy to the specific platform.

Thanks for the response, should the documentation be updated to remove global server level from its description. It is present that way which intends to mean it is like a global variable instead of account/platform level.

We will be updating the documentation
